# How can I add a contidion to a query which is combination of python and sql

Tags: python, sql, parameters, jinja2, prepared-statement

I have something which I really don't know the logic of, so I cannot imagine how to add what I want to the below query. There are example fields that I created below:
Select_company is a multi-select input parameter includes BMW, Mercedes, Audi etc.
company name is a column in my table.
Select_country is also a multi-select input parameter that includes all countries in the world. Country name is another column in my table.
I just want to say that if I choose BMW from the 'select_company' parameter, I want to see not all countries, the only United States, Germany, and Spain.
Can I add this condition to this query and receive what I want. I have a deadline for tomorrow. I really appreciate your help.

```
select * from "products"
where 
1 = 1

{% if select_company|length >0 %}
and company_name in ({{select_provider|array}})
{% endif%}


{% if select_country|length >0 %}
and country_name in ({{select_country|array}})
{% endif%}
```

Since I really dont know exactly what it is happening, I may not give proper title or tags. I am so sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL qmark parameters like in DBAPI will be passed in a way to protect you from injection, so you can’t pass the `company_name` and `country_name` columns as parameters.

Also, you really shouldn’t use Jinja2 or other templating tools because they open the door to injection, even if you control the queries, second layer injections exist and will affect template queries.

But your problem although very vague sounds like it should be solved in SQL alone. How depends on the SQL implementation you are using.